# Talend two DB inputs from single REST

Tags: talend

Trying to do following scheme in Talend ESB:

tREST_request ---- tXMLMap -- Split it to two DB_Inputs -- tXMLMap --- tREST_response

- getting ID from RESTrequest,
- then get some info from two different DBs by this ID
- and finally combine the result REST responses from both DB inputs

Talend do not allow me to combine both DB inputs to single XMLmap,
as i understand may be only one Main flow.
Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us how your job is currently set up? Maybe with just the one database input if you have that working.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not post image here inline, because of site policy (do not have enough rating). Here is link to image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2557698/talend.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by serializing the process, use global variable and hashes.
Not sure if it is a best solution but at least it is working.
Attached [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2557698/talend-solved.png) with flow.